# Using NULL class pointers, class member functions can be called. How is this possible?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public :
    void show()
    {
        cout << "A "  << endl;
    }

};
class B : public A
{
public :
    void show()
    {
        cout << "B "  << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A *a =NULL;
    a->show(); // Prints 'A'
    B *b =NULL;
    b->show(); // Prints 'B'
}
```

How is this getting printed and when we inherit `show` from `A` to `B`, how can `show()` be called using a `B` class object? What exactly happens when inherited `A` from `B`?

Comment: De-referencing a null pointer is undefined behavior. What compiler are you using that allowed such behavior?

Comment: I've just tried his code with g++ 4.8.1 and it prints A and B too.

Comment: Well, it´s still UB. The compiler etc. can do whatever they want. And as soon there is something virtual, it will break for sure.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. But to take a guess at why this happens; the "invisible" parameter for `this` passed to member functions is NULL, but it is never itself referenced, so the code "looks" to work, but it is really undefined behaviour. Anything could happen.

Comment: This is indeed undefined behavior but it is common practice not to check "this" parameter in non-virtual method call until data members are accessed. For instance in Microsoft standard library there is [GetSafeHwnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d64ehwhz.aspx) method that explicitly: "Returns m_hWnd, or NULL if the this pointer is NULL."

Comment: This has been asked before

Comment: @crashmstr wheres the link to the dup

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behavior, but a lot of implementations would behave the way you're seeing.  Consider this call:

```
a->show();
```

The compiler can see that A has no base class, and `show()` is not virtual.  So the only possible function to invoke is `A::show()`.  So great, invoke it!  All you need to do (if you're the compiler) is pass `a` as `this`, i.e. the hidden first argument to the function.  And if `this` is never used in the function, it's likely to work just fine.

Even so, this is not guaranteed to work, is non-portable, and is a bad idea.  Don't do it.  Your trousers might burn.